# Mirroring in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

I'm trying to set up mirroring between two sql 2008 databases on different servers in my internal network, as a test run before doing the same thing with two live servers in different locations.

When I actually try and switch the mirroring on the target DB (with
ALTER DATABASE testdb SET PARTNER = N'TCP://myNetworkAddress:5022') I'm getting an error telling me that the server network address can not be reached or does not exist. A little research suggests this is a fairly unhelpful message that pops up due to a number of possible causes, some of which are not directly related to the server existing or otherwise.

So far I've checked and tried the following to solve this problem:

- On the target server, I've verified that in SQL Configuration Manager that "Protocols for SQLEXPRESS" (my local installation is labelled SQLEXPRESS for some reason, even though querying SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') reveals that it's 64-bit Enterprise), and Client Protocols for SQL Native Client 10 all have TCP/IP enabled
- I'm using a utility program called CurrPorts to verify that there is a TCP/IP port with the same number specified by the mirroring setup (5022) is open and listening on my machine. Netstat verifies that both machines are listening on this port.
- I've run SELECT type_desc, port FROM sys.tcp_endpoints; and
  SELECT state_desc, role FROM sys.database_mirroring_endpoints to ensure that everything is set up as it should be. The only thing that confused me was the "role" returns 1 .. not entirely sure what that means.
- I've tried to prepare the DB correctly. I've taken backups of the database and the log file from the master DB and restored them on the target database with NORESTORE. I've tried turning mirroring on both while leaving them in the NORESTORE state and running an empty RESTORE ... neither seems to make much difference. Just as a test I also tried to mirror an inactive, nearly empty database that I created but that didn't work either.
- I've verified that neither server is behind a firewall (they're both on the same network, although on different machines)

I've no idea where to turn next. I've seen these two troubleshooting help pages:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189127.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337361.aspx

And as far as I can tell I've run through all the points to no avail.

One other thing I'm unsure of is the service accounts box in the wizard. For both databases I've been putting in our high-level access account name which should have full admin permissions on the database - I assumed this was the right thing to do.

I'm not sure where to turn next to try and troubleshoot this problem. Suggestions gratefully received.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

I think that SQL Express can only act as a witness server with this SQL feature, you might get better mileage on ServerFault though.

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Your network settings might be OK. We got quite non-informative error messages in MS SQL - the problem might be an authorization issue and the server still will be saying "network address can not be reached".

By the way, how the authentication is performed? A MSSQL service (on server1) itself must be runned as a valid db user (on server2, and vice versa) in order to make the mirroring work.